# How to use stuff using columns with same ID

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I will start with an sql table example

```
ID    Column

1     Name1
1     Name2
2     Name3
2     Name4
```

I want to use stuff but only when ID is the same.
Example in my output i want to take

```
 Name1,Name2 ->FirstRow
 Name3,Name4 ->SecondRow
```

Here is what i'm trying to do, but i'm getting all top values into one row

```
Select REPLACE(STUFF((SELECT top(10) CHAR(10) + convert(varchar(50),TrnDocumentID) + ' '+name 
                  FROM InventoryTrans  where TrnDocumentID=TrnDocumentID
                   FOR XML PATH ('')) , 1, 1, '') ,
          CHAR(10) , CHAR(13)+CHAR(10))
```

Also i wnt trnDocumentID to take it in different column but in same row

Comment: `WHERE TrnDocumentID=TrnDocumentID` is like having `WHERE 1 = 1`, it will always be true. Give your tables aliases and use them.

Comment: You need to correlate the inner `FOR XML` query with the outer one. For example, if you alias the outer table as `outer_table`, the inner query would be like `FROM InventoryTrans AS inner_table where inner_table.TrnDocumentID=outer_table.TrnDocumentID FOR XML...`

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
declare @tab table (ID int,    [Column] varchar(100))
insert into @tab select 1,     'Name1'
union
select 1,     'Name2'
union
select 2,     'Name3'
union
select 2,     'Name4'

select * from @tab

Select ID, REPLACE(STUFF((SELECT top(10) CHAR(10) + convert(varchar(50),ID) + ' '+[Column]
                  FROM @tab t_in where t_in.ID=t_out.ID
                   FOR XML PATH ('')) , 1, 1, ''),
          CHAR(10) , CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)) Grouped_Value
from @tab t_out
group by ID
```

you can always modify the Grouped_Value to remove the ID part.